# What does "Inclusive" means under benefits of a company?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I saw this in a vacancy that appeared on StackOverflow careers.

[image]

Does that mean gender is not considered in the workplace and there are equal opportunities?

Answer (score 7):

Judging from the iconography, yes that does appear to be what it means. We provide pre-defined icons, but it's up to the individual employer to add text to each one so the actual definition isn't necessarily clear.

[Other](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/noggin#benefits) [employers](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/paladin#benefits) have used that icon in this way so I think it's a safe bet that is what it means.

We're planning to standardise the benefits section so that these things become easily searchable.

Comment: Doesn't "inclusive" rather mean that *additional* measures are being taken to make e.g. women welcome in a profession that doesn't have that many? Given that equal opportunity is the legal minimum in the US and most of Europe anyway?

Comment: I may be entirely incorrect in this, but I do believe that you are misinterpreting the symbol itself, and therefore the intent of companies using it. I do believe you are taking the symbol to mean "employs both men and women" when I believe it actually is intended to mean "employs men, women, and LBGT" and that last part, is not so black and white in either the US nor UK nor EU.

Comment: @Bruce Look at the links to the other company pages. Most companies using that symbol use the words 'Inclusion and Diversity' which, as you say, promotes gender, racial and LGBT equality. Original poster mentioned equal opportunities and I agreed, feels like we're all saying the same thing, no?

Comment: Irrespective of it being US and EU law, calling it out indicates that a company actively promotes it. In an industry not famed for doing so that could be considered to be a good thing.

Comment: Not exactly as I believe when most people think of equal oportunity, they think of US EEO laws (equal employment opportunity) laws, and LGBT is a grey area legally.

Comment: I agree with your last statement entirely.

Comment: @Bruce hmmm, k, I could see some ambiguity there, but the intent behind the word 'Inclusive' is fairly unanimous these days. I think in that context the answer still stands

Comment: Haha your answer is spot on, or I would have made my own. :) I really need to start using that @ sign. lol my first comment was in reply to @Pekka웃